# What is the name for "designated" "oriented" "specialized" in this case?

Tags: terminology, programming

I'm writing a technical document but couldn't think of a better term than "designated" in this scenario.

I have a module which is general-purpose. I can tune it into a special-purpose one by doing certain configuration on it. So I need to collect meta-data that is specifically associated with this no longer general-purpose module.

How shall I call those data? "Designated data" just doesn't sound right. The data is accompanied by the module and varies in accordance with its type, after the tuning.

For example, module 1 can detect voice, therefore it has a "voice detection threshold". Module 2 can detect ultrasonic waves, therefore it has a "acoustic event detection count".

What is the best term? "Oriented data"?

Comment: Module-specific metadata

Comment: Hey! That's actually pretty good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

*Module-specific metadata*